# Get the iframe name from the source document

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have following iframe in a parent page:

```
<html>
....
<iframe src="child.html" name="variedName" id="variedId"></iframe>
...
</html>
```

Is there any way that make Javascript from `child.html` to get the `name` value or the `id` of the iframe that included it?

I need this because I want to add some markup around the iframe that is going to include `child.html` in the parent page using `window.parent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the quick and dirty solution would be to give the iframe the same name and id and access the iframe within the child page like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById(window.name);
```

Comment: Or you can use `parent.document.getElementsByName(window.name)[0];` (Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

Comment: Good point!  That's definitely a little more elegant that my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only if the pages share the same origin.

You can do something like:

```
var parent_window = window.parent;
iframes = parent_window.document.getElementsByTag("iframe");
if (iframes[0].window === window) {
    // found it
}
```

The `if` statement might need some tweaking but I think this works.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the presented solutions, You can use this:

```
parent.document.getElementsByName(window.name)[0];
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Or this:

```
parent.document.querySelector('iframe[src="'+location+'"]');
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Or this "frankencode":

```
(function(){
    for(var i=0,frames=parent.frames,l=frames.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(frames[i].window===window)
        {
            return frames[i].window;
        }
    }
})();
```

If you have jQuery:

```
$('iframe[name="'+window.name+'"]',parent); //method 1

$('iframe[src="'+location+'"]',parent); //method 2

$('iframe',parent).filter(function(){ //a different method
    return this.window===window;
}).eq(0);
```

And many more ways...